# Find out what processes are accessing my file

Tags: c#, file, networking, windows-7, locking

I have a single executable located on our network which is normally ran on up to 150 computers.  I made some updates to the program and I'm trying to replace the file with the updated version.  Problem is, I'm getting the "Action can't be completed because the file is open in another program" error.  I've restarted all of the machines that normally use the file, but I still get this message.

Is there any way to find out what process is locking it?
Is there a way to delete the file even though it's 'in use' by another process?  Going forward, is there a way to avoid this?

I've tried the following code (in addition to downloading a program called "Unlocker") to try to force it to delete, but no luck:

```
File.Delete("path to network file"); 
// and 
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DeleteFile(string path);
bool success = DeleteFile("path to network file");
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I tried searching before I submitted.  Also not asking for software.

Comment: Try renaming the original file.

Comment: I don't see how the close reason stated above applies as the OP is not requesting a tool or library, rather inquiring about a programmatic way to find the "owners" of a file and how to programmatically override file owership by other processes. While the questions seems a bit broad it would appear to be on-topic. Voting to re-open.